# Error message when using tkz-euclide that I can't explain

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am trying to use tkz-euclide but keep getting this error message,! LaTeX Error: File `tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex' not found. and can't figure out why.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Book One}

    Lets start with a few definitions;\\
        a postulate is:\\
        suggest or assume the existence, fact, or truth of (something) as a  basis for reasoning, discussion, or belief.\\
        An axiom is\\
        a statement or proposition which is regarded as being established, accepted, or self-evidently true.\\

    \section{Postulates}
        \subsection{Postulate 1}
A straight line may be drawn from any one point to any other point, but this  does not mean there is no other line that there cannot be more than more than one such line.

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 

\tkzDefPoint(1.25,0){B} 
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}

\end{tikzpicture}

     \subsection{Postulate 2}
         Aterminated line can be produced indefinitely.
    
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
\tkzDefPoint(1.25,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(-0.75,0){C} 
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){D}  
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed]{A,C}
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed]{B,D}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](A){$A$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[below](B){$B$}

    \subsection{Postulate 3}
        A circle can be drawn with any centre and any radius.
    
    \subsection{Postulate 4}
        All right angles are equal to one another.
    
    \subsection{postulate 5}
            If a straight line falling on two straight lines makes the interior angles on the same side of it taken together less than two right angles, then the two straight lines, if produced indefinitely, meet on that side on which the sum of angles is lesss than two right angles.
        
        
\end{document}
```

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If I run your example that file is found `(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-triangles.
tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-triangles.tex`  but I then get `! Undefined control sequence.
\tkz@node #1-> \pgfinterruptboundingbox \path` Note 2022/09/23 is quite recent so check your system is up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- (minimized example)
- add missing `tikzpicture` environment
- replace `{...}` by `(...)` at both `\tkzDrawSegment` commands.

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Postulate 1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(1.25,0){B} 
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection{Postulate 2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(1.25,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(-0.75,0){C} 
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){D}  
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,D)
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](B){$B$}
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you I can't believe I din't include the environment! a case of can't see the forest for the trees

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the last version of `tkz-euclide` 2.5.
I removed the file `tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex` and I forgot to delete in `tkz-euclide.sty`. You have three solutions:

1. Dowload the version 2.5
2. or in tkz-euclide.sty you can delete the line `\input{tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex}`
3. or you can place the file  `tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex' from an older version.

Explanation : 'draw-polygon' is more general than `draw-triangle` because now you must first define the triangle with the options : equilateral, pythagore, gold ... before you draw. And now the only options for drawing are the style of the lines.